# How to center and crop an image with an Image control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I have an image file that is rectangular, say 300px by 200px

I would like to display it in an Image control that is 100px by 100px.

How can I say to the Image control to display the image like this

[image]

instead of like this?

[image]

(In red is my Image control and in black is my image file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a centered image, you may set `UniformToFill` on an `ImageBrush`:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="..." Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your image code, in xaml, add this property:

```
Stretch="UniformToFill"
```

It will adjust image to fill all of the square without changing his proportion.

Comment: Thanks it helps. I think now it sets the position of the image at 0,0 (top-left). Is it easy to indicate "Center the image"?